# Using jquery ui dialog and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, filemaker

I am trying to minimize jumping pages around so I have utilized an accordion jquery ui object to nest what the customer needs to see.  Under the project accordion I want to list dialog buttons that have the project name.  When the customer clicks on the dialog a box will pop out showing the project detail info.  I have managed to get everything together under the right accordion but I can't seem to get the dialog button to display each project detail.  I can get the first project only, all of the projects or have it listed as it is now.

The accordion and dialog elements are working great, I just can't get each button dialog to contain the unique `projectID` data.

```
        foreach ($r->getRecords() as $project){
$projectId = $project->getField('ID_Project');
$projectName = $project->getField('Project_Name');
$projectDate = $project->getField('Date_Start');
$projectStaff = $project->getField('Staff');
$projectReport = $project->getField('MasterReport');

        echo '<div id="dialog" title="Project Detail">';
        echo '<p>';
        echo '<b>Affidavit:</b> &nbsp;' . $projectId . '<br>';
        echo '<b>Project Name:</b> &nbsp;' . $projectName . '<br>';
        echo '<b>Project Date:</b> &nbsp;' . $projectDate . '<br>';
        echo '<b>Verifier:</b> &nbsp;' . $projectStaff . '<br>';
        echo '<b>Report Link:</b> &nbsp;' . "<a href='includes/php/containerBridge.php?path=".urlencode($projectReport)."'>Click here to download PDF Report</a><br>";
        echo '</p>';
        echo '</div>';


        echo '<button id="opener">' . $projectName . '</button><br>';
}
```

Here is the script in the header portion I am using:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  show: {
    effect: "blind",
    duration: 1000
  },
  hide: {
    effect: "explode",
    duration: 1000
  }
});

$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
});
</script>
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
  heightStyle: "fill"
});
});
$(function() {
$( "#accordion-resizer" ).resizable({
  minHeight: 250,
  minWidth: 200,
  resize: function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "refresh" );
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: ID's in html have to be unique, you should use classes instead in your loop.

Comment: echo '<button class="opener" id="$projectId">' . $projectName . '</button><br>'; Then bind to the opener class and get the Id from id property and load the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you check the usage of [jqueryui-dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog)?

First you should generate jquery dialogs by using `$("#id").dialog`; then you should bind `click()` functions to each button.**Note**: Dialog `<div>` and `<button>` always work in pairs, so you should avoid using same `id` on each `<div>`.

So modify your php code, like this:

```
foreach($r->getRecords() as $project){
  //getField...
  echo '<div class="dlg" id="dialog-'.$projectId.'" title="Project Detail">';
  //...echo other contents
  echo '<button class="dlg_btn" data-dlg="'.$projectId.'">' . $projectName . '</button><br>';
}
```

After that, your html output should like this:

```
<div class="dlg" id="dialog-1">
  <p>....
</div>
<button class="dlg_btn" data-dlg="1">Project 1</button>
```

Now your javascript should be:

```
<script>
//do bindings
$(".dlg").dialog({
  autoOpen: false
});
//button click callback
$(".dlg_btn").click(function(){
  var projectid = $(this).attr("data-dlg");
  $("#dialog-"+projectid).dialog("open");
});
</script>
```

Note the `id` connect each div-button pair.But, if your `<button>` is always placed just after the `<div>` of the project, there is a more simple way to code:

```
$(".dlg_btn").click(function(){
  $(this).prev().dialog("open");
});
```

I've coded them on jsfiddle: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Bandon/uafzmu33/)

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks so much!  Also thanks to the two commenters, everyone was right on